# Route average, maximum and distance to maximum slope

Tags: qgis, mapwindow

I have a road network, consisting of a polyline shapefile, each record of its attribute table being a  stretch of the road network ("stretch" = any record of the attribute table of the polyline shapefile).

**the maximum slope**

This data should then be written on the attribute's table by creating a new field.

I'v searched the net looking for an extension or a plugin to do this in an automated fashion, but, apart from an extension for ArcGis, which calculates road slope in a very confusing way, nothing more was found.

So I ask and encourage the community for a solution, be it a plugin or any other method, especially that can be used with open source GIS programs like QGIS or MapWindow.

I also make available an old extension for ArcView 3.x, that uses a PolylineM class to find route slopes, and that can illustrate (or be a guide for) the way for a more updated plugin:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpkh6rhgrx8eqjc/route_slope_5_3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Comment: Without a question mark in your question body it is hard to determine what you are asking.  If you are asking the community to develop a plugin using an old extension as the specification then that is far too broad for focussed Q&A.

Comment: You may not understand what I want, but Micha did very well. I'm not interested on this forum any more. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using GRASS-GIS (even though you did not tag your question as related to GRASS).

The GRASS module `v.rast.stats` will add several univariate statistics from a raster map to the vector's attribute table. So first import into GRASS both the road network, and your elevation raster. Each stretch of the road will get a unique GRASS category. Use the GRASS module `r.slope.aspect` to get a slope raster from the elevation. Then run `v.rast.stats` ([man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.rast.stats.html)) with the parameter `method=average,maximum` and you'll have answers to (1) and (2).